# Python-pptx Not able to remove/delete existing graph from ppt

Tags: python, python-pptx

pptx library to edit/add content to a ppt.

I am adding a chart using below code to a slide but not able to delete the existing one so both are overlapping.

Actually  wanted to delete existing chart before adding new chart at same place.

I am using below code as per doc.

```
  chart_data = ChartData()
  chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
  chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
  x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
  zz = ninth_sld.shapes.add_chart( XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy,          chart_data)
  #ninth_slide.shapes.clear()
  chart1 = zz.chart
  chart1.replace_data(chart_data)
```

Comment: @scanny can you please answer this

Comment: API to delete shapes does not exist yet.